# Checking differential equation solution

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

I have this differential equation:

```
eq=D[ψ[r],r]+A*ψ[r]-(B/(A*r))ψ[r]==0;
```

And `DSolve` sucessfully solves it:

```
sol = DSolve[eq,ψ[r],r];
```

But when I check by replacing all, in this case it doesn't replace the derivative of the function:

```
Simplify[eq/.sol]
```

Derivative still must be replaced too. If I do:

```
Simplify[eq/.sol/.D[sol,r]]
```

Then this gives `True`.

In other cases *Mathematica* replaced the function and its derivatives in one shot. What's happening in this case?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Can I ask Mathematica to replace the arguments of my functions with a replacement rule?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32137/can-i-ask-mathematica-to-replace-the-arguments-of-my-functions-with-a-replacemen/32139#32139)

Comment: No, it's a different case. Look here: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CheckTheResultsOfDSolve.html. This states da if I do like that, it is sufficient to verify my solution. But in this particular case, I have to do an extra substitution.

Comment: Try `sol = DSolve[eq, \[Psi], r]` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `DSolve[eq,f,x]` you get a rule for the function. When you use `DSolve[eq,f[x],x]` you get a rule for the function evaluated at value `x`.

When you use `f[x]->blah`, Mathematica will replace all occurrences of `f[x]` but it will leave the occurrences of `f'[x]` untouched. That happens because you have not defined the function `f`, so Mathematica does not know that it should create another replacement rule (your `D[sol,r]`).

When you use `f->blah`, Mathematica replaces all occurrences of `f` and that includes not only `f[x]` but also `Derivative[1][f][x]` (which is the internal representation of `f'[x]`).