# Checking the solution of a differential equation with a given solution

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

I can't verify the solution of this differential equation.

```
 eqn = y'[x] == x*y[x]^(1/2)
```

where:

```
sol = {{y -> x^4/16}}
```

When I tried the ReplaceAll statement (/.) to verify the solution I get:

```
In[6]:= eqn /. sol

Out[6]= {Derivative[1][(x^4/16)][x] == x Sqrt[((x^4)/16)[x]]}
```

Instead of {True}. I have checked on:

- [Checking differential equation solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32739/checking-differential-equation-solution)
- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveSolutionVerification.html

And I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm just looking for some pointers or tips to see what I can do.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. (Your post is not formatted so well at this point -- sorry.  Don't format code as TeX. You want to make it easy to copy and paste back into *Mathematica*.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To verify ODE solution, use the functional method, as described in [tutorial/DSolveSolutionVerification.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveSolutionVerification.html) i.e. use `y` and not `y[x]` in the `DSolve` command.

Sometimes, as in this case, you have to help it a little also using `Simplify` as mentioned in the above link.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For your example:

```
ClearAll[y, x]
ode = y'[x] == x Sqrt[y[x]];
sol = DSolve[ode, y, x]
Simplify[ode /. sol, 
 Assumptions -> Element[{x, C[1]}, Reals] && x > 0 && C[1] > 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you do not use the assumptions, then Mathematica does not know that the sqrt is real or complex. Here is without the assumptions:

```
ClearAll[y, x]
ode = y'[x] == x Sqrt[y[x]];
sol = DSolve[ode, y, x]
Simplify[ode /. sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, I always wished Mathematica has an `odetest()` function as in Maple, as it makes it little easier. This is the same thing in Maple

```
ode := diff(y(x),x)= x*sqrt(y(x));
sol:=dsolve(ode,y(x));
odetest(sol,ode);
           0
```

If the answer is zero, then the solution satisfies the ODE.

ps. I just saw your edit and you wanted to verify `x^4/16`. Ok, in this case, you write this:

```
ode = y'[x] == x Sqrt[y[x]];
sol2 = y -> Function[{x}, x^4/16];
Simplify[ode /. sol2, Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The idea is to use `Function`, so that it will work with derivatives.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about the Assumptions option and was missing the  Function thing, even though i read it i didn't quite got it. Now i see whats need to  be done. :D, thanks again.

Comment: Shouldn't the `eq`s be `ode`s?

Comment: @BenjaminMaier yes ofcourse, thanks. These were typos. Must be I had `eq` there before from op code, and forgot to change it.

Comment: great! :) thanks for the solution btw, helped me a great deal the other day